# Is there such a thing as Limited Simultaneous-User Number in Google Spreadsheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I would like to limit my spreadsheet to 1 simultaneous user. I will share this spreadsheet with my colleagues and whole company (nearly 20 people, a small company:)) will make some changes on it. But there is a script on the spreadsheet and it uses some last_blabla informations, for example last_user etc. So I'm afraid script may get confused if more than 1 user make changes simultaneously. Maybe I'm being tighed-arsed or ignorent. But does anyone know how to scrict the simultaneous-user number on Google Drive in generel or just for Spreadsheets.

Or is there a way?

Comment: ``lock service``

Comment: You can't limit the number of browsers that can open the same Google Drive file. There is a mechanism Google uses to prevent use of Google Drive as a CDN, but you aren't going to trigger it with that kind of use.